# Problem with powershell and using script to recieve mail

Tags: windows, powershell

I am newbie in powershell. :(
But I am configuring mail notifications using powershell with the gmail mail server, everything is ok but I want to add the output of a script in the mail body.

[This is the image of the command to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCo5b.png)

```
$username   = 'test@gmail.com'
$password   = '*****'
$secstr     = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$body = C:\Users\esanchez\Desktop\script.ps1
$hash = @{
    from       = "test@gmail.com"
    to         = "receptor@gmail.com"
    subject    = "test"
    smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port       = "587"
    body       = GU
    credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
    usessl     = $true
    verbose    = $true
}

Send-MailMessage  -body $body @hash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `C:\Users\esanchez\Desktop\script.ps1` contain the script shown in the image?  If so I think you're close.  Just change that line to either include `| Out-String` or `| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` at the end so it converts your output into something you can send in the body and then update the body in `$hash` to use `$body`.  Finally fix the actual command line

```
$username   = 'test@gmail.com'
$password   = '*****'
$secstr     = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$body = C:\Users\esanchez\Desktop\script.ps1 | Out-String  # or | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 
$hash = @{
    from       = "test@gmail.com"
    to         = "receptor@gmail.com"
    subject    = "test"
    smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port       = "587"
    body       = $body   # update to use $body
    credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
    usessl     = $true
    verbose    = $true
}

Send-MailMessage  @hash  # remove body parameter here since you are already passing it in with the hashtable
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try what you tell me and I'll go back to see if it works

Comment: Hi Daniel, i have a little question. please can i help me

Answer (score 0):

Hello if everything works correct but only with Out-String

[Test Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD0Rz.png)

$body = C:\Users\esanchez\Desktop\script.ps1 | Out-String

but when i use

$body = C:\Users\esanchez\Desktop\script.ps1 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

I have a error, How could I format the mail?

[Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD0Rz.png)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Reason for this is in your script your last command is the `Format-Table` command.  Unfortunately with that there you cannot use `ConvertTo-Html` because `Format-Table` changes the objects into special format objects.  Instead what you can do is change that `Format-Table` command to  a `Select-Object` command.  Then either `Out-String` or `ConvertTo-Html` should work.  Hope that made sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time